# Can I make dice rolling with gyroscope in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-sensors

So, the idea is that there are several dice on the screen and the user needs to shake their phone to roll the dice (or push a button in case they don't have a gyroscope in their phone). The dice should be banging on the screen "walls" like they're in a box or something. At the end all the dice stop on one of their sides. Is there ANY way it can be accomplished with pure React Native/Expo? Any advice is appreciated.
And if this one is impossible, can the user at least press the button for the dice to start rolling on the screen?

Comment: how can we create dice in react native ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sensors using:

> https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors

or if you are using Expo:

> https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/gyroscope/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know about this library, I was actually asking about the physics of the dice rolling